# What keys should I press to activate c_CTRL-D in vim?

Tags: vim

I don't get how to activate this key c_CTRL-D in vim . I saw the  document and understood the function of this operator_motion combination. But I don't see the way how to trigger it. Pressing button 
C and then CTRL + D but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`c_CTRL-D` in the help documentation means pressing `CTRL-D` while *command-line editing*. For example, `:e<c-d>` will list out all commands starting with `e`.

From `:h`:

```
          WHAT          PREPEND    EXAMPLE  ~
          Normal mode command          :help x
          Visual mode command     v_       :help v_u
          Insert mode command     i_       :help i_<Esc>
          Command-line command    :    :help :quit
          Command-line editing    c_       :help c_<Del>
          Vim command argument    -    :help -r
          Option              '    :help 'textwidth'
          Regular expression      /    :help /[
        See |help-summary| for more contexts and an explanation.
```

Answer (score 4):

In Vim's help, that kind of prefix means *mode*.
So that `c_` means *Command-Line editing*, so you can activate this key combination in the command mode which you can enter by pressing `:` (colon) in normal mode.

You will see list of commands that matches characters in front of the cursor by pressing `CTRL-D` in the command mode. For example, if you pressed `:se` in normal mode, then pressed `CTRL-D`, you will see list of commands that start with `se`.

You can see list of prefixes in the following help entry:
`:help help-context`